# I need help renaming an element in an array

Tags: java, arrays, rename

I'm doing a java project at school and we were giving the following problem:

> #### rename – changes the name of an existing sheet
>
> `public int rename(String currentName, String newName)`
>
> `rename` is passed two sheet names. Renaming should only be performed if the `currentName` sheet name is in the list and the `newName` sheet name isn’t. Otherwise `rename` does nothing (i.e. the list is unaffected). 
>   If the `currentName` is successfully changed to the `newName` then the method returns the index position of the sheet renamed. Otherwise it returns `-1`.

This is what I have so far

```
public int rename(String currentName, String newName) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i=0; i<SheetsNames.length; i++) {
        if (SheetsNames[i].equals(currentName)) {
            SheetsNames[i] = newName;
                return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I got the renaming part but I can't get it to not rename it as something with the same name

Comment: What makes you think that it will still do something if the `currentName` is not in the `Array`? Have you tested it with an element that isn't contained and it changed an element? If so please [edit] your post to include this scenario

Comment: `if (newName.equals(currentName) { return -1; }` ? In a tiny "homework case" this doesn't add a whole lot.

Comment: What is `SheetsNames`? As far as I can tell from syntax highlights and the fact that normal variables start with lower case, I'd assume you're accessing a type definition as opposed to a variable.

Comment: *"but I can't get it to not rename it as something with the same name"* how could you perform the correct boolean evaluation in a one hand, and on the other hand not find how to perform the 99% similar boolean evaluation ?

Comment: Is SheetNames a list or an array, you mention both?

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the SheetNames and store any instances of a currentName's index in a variable called index while also checking if the newName is present in the list. If there is an instance of newName automatically return -1. But if there is no newName in the list then an instance of currentName's index will be stored in the index variable if it is present. If there are none then the function returns -1 anyways because that is what index is initialized as.

```
public int rename(String currentName, String newName) {
    int index = -1;
    for (int i=0; i<SheetsNames.length; i++) {
        if (SheetsNames[i].equals(newName))
            return -1;
        if (SheetsNames[i].equals(currentName))
            index = i;
    }
    if (index != -1)
        SheetNames[index] = newName;
    return index; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

1) Input parameters are validated

2) Looks for string in array and returns the index

```
public class SheetNames {

    public Integer changeSheetName(String[] sheetNames, String currentName, String newName) {

        if (sheetNames == null || sheetNames.length == 0 || currentName == null || newName == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input");
        }

        Integer replacedIndex = Arrays.asList(sheetNames).indexOf(currentName);
        if (replacedIndex != -1) {
            sheetNames[replacedIndex] = newName;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sheetNames));
        return replacedIndex;
    }
}
```

**Junit Tests:-**

```
public class SheetNamesTest {

    private SheetNames sheetNames;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        sheetNames = new SheetNames();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReplaceSheetName() {
        String[] sheetNamesArr = {"dennis", "john", "dan"};
        Assert.assertEquals(new Integer(1), sheetNames.changeSheetName(sheetNamesArr, "john", "peter"));

        String[] sheetNamesArr2 = {"john", "dan"};
        Assert.assertEquals(new Integer(0), sheetNames.changeSheetName(sheetNamesArr2, "john", "peter"));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldNotReplaceSheetName() {
        String[] sheetNamesArr = {"dennis", "johnhunt", "dan"};
        Assert.assertEquals(new Integer(-1), sheetNames.changeSheetName(sheetNamesArr, "john", "peter"));
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void shouldThrowExceptionWhenSheetNameIsNull() {
        sheetNames.changeSheetName(null, "john", "peter");
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void shouldThrowExceptionWhenSheetNameIsEmpty() {
        String[] sheetNamesArr = {};
        sheetNames.changeSheetName(sheetNamesArr, "john", "peter");
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void shouldThrowExceptionWhenCurrentNameIsNull() {
        String[] sheetNamesArr = {"dennis", "johnhunt", "dan"};
        sheetNames.changeSheetName(sheetNamesArr, null, "peter");
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void shouldThrowExceptionWhenNewNameIsNull() {
        String[] sheetNamesArr = {"dennis", "johnhunt", "dan"};
        sheetNames.changeSheetName(sheetNamesArr, "john", null);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the comments in the below code:

```
public int rename(String currentName, String newName) {
    int currentNameindex = -1; // set the initial position of currentName

    for (int i = 0; i < SheetsNames.length; i++) {
        if (currentNameindex < 0)  // currentName has not been found yet 
            if (SheetsNames[i].equals(currentName))
                currentNameindex = i;  // save the position of currentName 

        if (SheetsNames[i].equals(newName))  // newName is found in the list
            return -1;  
    }

    if (currentNameindex > 0)  // currentName is found in the list
        SheetsNames[currentNameindex] = newName;  // rename the list item

    return currentNameindex;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Loop through your SheetsNames and check if it contains newName already (if yes, then you dont want to update so return -1)

```
for(String name: SheetsNames){
   if(name.equals(newName) return -1;
}
```

Now we are certain the new name is not in the list! Lets check if there is a name same as currentName in there, if yes return its index.

```
for(int i=0;i<SheetsNames.length;i++){

   if(name.equals(currentName){
     SheetsNames[i] = newName;
     return i;
   }
}
return -1; //its not in SheetsNames, so we return -1
```

Comment: The only point to doing the check is to avoid looping through all members.